# Symfony2: error deploying

Tags: deployment, symfony

I have an error when deploying manually my symfony project into my server. I can't do any console command even cache:clear. I have used the :

```
php app/console cache:clear --no-warmup
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: argv in /app/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 57
PHP Warning:  array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /app/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 61
PHP Warning:  array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /app/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 294
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /app/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 269
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8-pl0-gentoo
cache-control: no-cache
date: Fri, 10 Feb 2012 15:31:08 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: argv in <b>/app/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php</b> on line <b>57</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in <b>/app/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php</b> on line <b>61</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in <b>/app/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php</b> on line <b>294</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/app/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php</b> on line <b>269</b><br />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
        <title>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</title>
        <style>
            /* Copyright (c) 2010, Yahoo! Inc. All rights rese
```

I have printed the **app/logs/dev.log** error:

```
[2012-02-10 13:04:58] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Acme\DemoBundle\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-02-10 13:04:58] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Controller\ControllerListener::onCoreController". [] []
[2012-02-10 13:04:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-02-10 13:04:59] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
[2012-02-10 13:04:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-02-10 13:04:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-02-10 13:04:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-02-10 13:04:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\CacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-02-10 13:04:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-02-10 13:04:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
```

I have no idea and no description in the web

Please help me

Thanks
Sam

Comment: Are you doing this from a console window?  Seems a bit bizarre.  When happens if you just do: php app/console?  And if that blows up then make a simple hello.php file and make sure it runs.  I suppose it's possible that something in your php.ini might be kicking in.

Comment: I have tried  a php app/console and i have the same probkem... I have made à php file which contains php version fubction and it works...

Comment: And you are running this directly from a console window and not through a web page?

Comment: Hi cerad. I'm running this directly from a console window

Comment: I have found thé solution.... I have totally dessinstall the server and use a debian one... Now it works!! Capifony it is so cool :)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I have reinstall my server and now I use a debian one in order to use a gentoo distribution.

I have now no problem.

It works perfectly...

Thanks for all

Comment: That is a very unhelpful answer, what if you are here trying to troubleshoot the problem on Debian?  Clearly something else is amiss.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an issue track which have brought some light to me:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3323

After reading that I researched and I've found that the problem raises in PHP CLI configuration (php.ini file). The register_argc_argv directive must be enabled:

```
register_argc_argv=On
```

Or if you cannot modify the php.ini file, you can change it in time execution pasing as an argument to php:

```
php -d register_argc_argv=On your_script.php
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. I was getting a ContextErrorException caused by Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php line 283

Answer (score 2):

did you try :

> **php-cli** app/console cache:clear

instead of :

> **php** app/console cache:clear